# SCSS and calculation

Tags: css, sass

I'm new in scss and working on an new Gooey loader. You can view my code here:
*http://codepen.io/muuvmuuv/pen/qOWagM?editors=010*

The bug that im trying to fix: In the animation-delay, i want to *subtract 0.425* multiple *$i for loop* so its *anyway X.0s*.

```
@for $i from 1 through $numOfBalls {
  &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
     transform: rotate(360deg/$numOfBalls * $i) translate3d(0,$transY,0); 
     animation-delay: (3.4s / $numOfBalls) * $i - (0.425s * $i);
  }
}
```

Hope someone can help me or finish my project faster then me, but I appreciate hints.
At the end it should look like this:
http://www.materialup.com/posts/spinner-loader-gooey-light-effect

Comment: I don't think you've thought through your formula very hard.  For every step through your loop, you're getting a value of `0s` for your animation-delay.

Comment: Thats why im asking for a hint. Im new in programming with scss and calculating in it. @cimmanon

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't due to the animation delay but rather you haven't set `animation-timing-function` on the ball being animated.

```
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

You also had 1 too many steps which was causing it to reset later than wanted.

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/stewartside/pen/pjzNow)

- [Animation Timing Function MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function)

Comment: Okey thank you. But it should scale one after one and after the 8 again.

Comment: I mean in size. I linked the GIF im using